# Are street crimes random?

Tags: la-noire

In L.A. Noire, do the street crime dispatch calls occur at pre-defined events in each crime case? If I miss one, is it lost forever unless I replay the case (or the entire game) or are they basically randomized and without a set time and place that triggers them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are basically randomized, though I think some are tied to particular times of day.  Once you complete all the cases for a particular "desk", you can go back and play it in free play, which allows you to complete any street crimes that you might have missed.